# Kendo UI File Upload on Safari - problems with uploading files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, kendo-ui, safari

I'm using kendo ui file upload widget, with async configuration.
It's working ok on all browser except of Safari.
In Safari the upload sends a request to my upload handler, but the request body is empty or just contains file's name.
How to configure it to work? Maybe i could switch to iframe-based implementation that performs normal upload in the bacgkground, but how to achieve that with current version of Kendo UI?

HAR:

{"pageref":"http://localhost:3805/Details/Show/0?entity=EndCustomerServiceRequest","startedDateTime":"2016-12-15T15:48:56.644Z","time":20,"request":{"method":"POST","url":"http://localhost:3805/FaAttachments/Upload","headers":[{"name":"Origin","value":"http://localhost:3805"},{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWVyNKFW88DuUTqSL"},{"name":"Accept","value":"*/*; q=0.5, application/json"},{"name":"Referer","value":"http://localhost:3805/Details/Show/0?entity=EndCustomerServiceRequest"}],"queryString":[],"cookies":[],"headersSize":-1,"bodySize":-1,"postData":{"mimeType":"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWVyNKFW88DuUTqSL","text":"------WebKitFormBoundaryWVyNKFW88DuUTqSL--\r\n"}},"response":{"status":200,"statusText":"OK","headers":[{"name":"Date","value":"Thu, 15 Dec 2016 15:48:56 GMT"},{"name":"X-AspNet-Version","value":"4.0.30319"},{"name":"X-Powered-By","value":"ASP.NET"},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"2"},{"name":"X-AspNetMvc-Version","value":"5.2"},{"name":"Server","value":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json; charset=utf-8"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"private"},{"name":"X-SourceFiles","value":"=?UTF-8?B?QzpcZGV2c1xDb25maWd1cmF0b3JcV2ViQ29uZmlndXJhdG9yXEZhQXR0YWNobWVudHNcVXBsb2Fk?="}],"cookies":[],"content":{"size":2,"mimeType":"application/json"},"redirectURL":"","headersSize":-1,"bodySize":2},"cache":{},"timings":{"blocked":0,"dns":-1,"connect":-1,"send":-1,"wait":-1,"receive":4,"ssl":-1}}

Comment: Do the Kendo Upload demos work in Safari?  If not, then either a bug in Kendo or in Safari.  If yes, then you need to post your code so that we can explore what you are doing differently from the "accepted" use.

Answer (score 1):

Answerring myself: to make it work you need to set the 'name' attribute on the input field. Without it Safari doesnt send file contents.